# Programmatically changing List Preference Selection

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have been trying for so long top try to figure out how to change the selection in a list preference without the user actually doing it. What i need to do is have a method that randomly selects one of the options in the List Preference. This will only be done if the "randomize" check box is checked. That part I can get to work properly, but it's the actual randomization that isn't working. Here is what I have:

Here is the list preference

```
<ListPreference
            android:key="location_preference"
            android:title="@string/location"
            android:summary="@string/location_summary"
            android:entries="@array/locations"
            android:entryValues="@array/locationValues"
            android:defaultValue="Canyon"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/location" />
```

and here is the method that I came up with to randomize the selection

```
protected static void setRandomLocation(Context context){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(context);
    Set<String> locs = preferences.getStringSet("location_preference", null);
    int idx = new Random().nextInt(locs.toArray().length);
    String random = (String) (locs.toArray()[idx]);
    preferences.edit().putString("location_preference", random);
    preferences.edit().commit();
}
private static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}
```

What am i doing wrong / how should I do it?

EDIT: So I tried the following to try and fix it, and it didn't work.

```
protected static void setRandomLocation(Context context){
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(context);
    String curr = preferences.getString("location_preference", null);
    int idx = new Random().nextInt(res.getStringArray(R.array.locationValues).length);
    String random = (String) (res.getStringArray(R.array.locationValues)[idx]);
    if(random == curr)
        setRandomLocation(context);
    preferences.edit().putString("location_preference", random);
    preferences.edit().commit();
}
```

Comment: Cannot check this at the moment. Change `if(random == curr)` to `if (random.equals(curr))`. And ad a return statement otherwise it will call the editor also more times. Great chance the first curr is put in again then when the stack unwinds.

Comment: Tell me please which values can idx obtain in `int idx = new Random().nextInt(6);` ?

Comment: a random integer from 0 to 6, not including 6

Comment: stupid mistake with the == and .equals. Where would a return statement go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Set<String> locs = preferences.getStringSet("location_preference", null);
```

There is no stringset for  `android:key="location_preference"` there. There is only one string:

```
    String location = preferences.getString("location_preference", null;
```

You have to get all strings from your predefined array `android:entryValues="@array/locationValues"` and take one randomly from them and save one to "location_preference".

Comment: Ofcourse not. Try for yourself. If you have problems post he code and we can see.